# How do "References to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type" work with >2 args?

Tags: java

How do so-called "References to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type" work when there are more than two args? I found a relevant [tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), but it's not explicit on that

> The following is an example of a reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type:
>
> ```java
> String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
>    "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
> Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
> ```
>
> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference `String::compareToIgnoreCase` would have the formal parameter list (String a, String b), where a and b are arbitrary names used to better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)`.
>
> Similarly, the method reference `String::concat` would invoke the method `a.concat(b)`.

I made a simple experiment, and it seems it work as follows: take the first arg and invoke the method on the rest of the args

```java
// these are equivalent
TernaryOperator<String> ternaryOperator = (el1, el2, el3) -> el1.replaceAll(el2, el3);
TernaryOperator<String> ternaryOperator = String::replaceAll;
```

```java
interface TernaryOperator<T> {
    T apply(T el1, T el2, T el3);
}
```

However, I'm confused how it squares with the word "arbitrary". If it's always the first arg, it's not that arbitrary after all

> (of an action, a decision, a rule, etc.) not seeming to be based on a reason, **system** *[if it's always the first arg, it seems like a system to me]* or plan and sometimes seeming unfair
>
> [Oxford Learners Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/arbitrary?q=arbitrary)

If it's not documented, then it may technically be unsafe to rely on behavior of "References to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type" in production projects

So what is it?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the English here. “Arbitrary” does not mean an “arbitrary parameter”. Read it again - it says “arbitrary *object*”. Since any object of that type can be passed to the first parameter, it’s a method on an *arbitrary* object.

Comment: @Sweeper thank you, but, still, is it specified in the official documentation? Does it mention something along the lines of "take the first arg and invoke the method on the rest of the args"?

Comment: Don’t focus on the lambda’s parameter list but on the method invocation: `el1.replaceAll(el2, el3)`. One argument is special, `el1`, which is called the method receiver. In your example, the receiver is an arbitrary object, in contrast to `BinaryOperator<String> op = "hello world"::replaceAll;` where the method receiver is not an arbitrary object but a very specific instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the English. “Arbitrary” does not mean an "arbitrary parameter" will be the invocation target. Read it again - it says "arbitrary *object*" - the object that is the invocation target is arbitrary. Any object of that type can be passed to the first parameter, so it's "arbitrary".

See the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3) for more details. The most relevant part is probably this part (emphasis mine)

> - If the form is `ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier`, the body of the invocation method similarly has the effect of a method
>   invocation expression for a compile-time declaration which is the
>   compile-time declaration of the method reference expression. Run-time
>   evaluation of the method invocation expression is as specified in
>   §15.12.4.3, §15.12.4.4, and §15.12.4.5, where:
>
>   - The invocation mode is derived from the compile-time declaration as specified in §15.12.3.
>   - If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, **then the target reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation
>     method**. Otherwise, there is no target reference.
>   - If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then **the arguments to the method invocation expression (if any) are the second
>     and subsequent formal parameters** of the invocation method. Otherwise,
>     the arguments to the method invocation expression are the formal
>     parameters of the invocation method.